# Recursive post order tree traversal without creating new nodes

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, tail-recursion, postorder

I want to define a generalized tail recursive tree traversal that works for all kinds of multi-way trees. This works fine with pre-order and level-order, but I'm having trouble to implement post order traversals. Here is the multi-way tree I am working with:

[image: multi-way tree]

Desired order: EKFBCGHIJDA

As long as I don't care about tail recursion post order traversal is easy:

```js
const postOrder = ([x, xs]) => {
  xs.forEach(postOrder);
  console.log(`${x}`);
};

const Node = (x, ...xs) => ([x, xs]);

const tree = Node("a",
  Node("b",
    Node("e"),
    Node("f",
      Node("k"))),
  Node("c"),
  Node("d",
    Node("g"),
    Node("h"),
    Node("i"),
    Node("j")));

postOrder(tree);
```

The tail recursive approach, on the other hand, is quite cumbersome:

```js
const postOrder = (p, q) => node => {
  const rec = ({[p]: x, [q]: forest}, stack) => {
      if (forest.length > 0) {
        const [node, ...forest_] = forest;
        stack.unshift(...forest_, Node(x));
        return rec(node, stack);
      }

      else {
        console.log(x);
        
        if (stack.length > 0) {
          const node = stack.shift();
          return rec(node, stack);
        }

        else return null;
      }
    };

  return rec(node, []);
};

const Node = (x, ...xs) => ([x, xs]);

const tree = Node("a",
  Node("b",
    Node("e"),
    Node("f",
      Node("k"))),
  Node("c"),
  Node("d",
    Node("g"),
    Node("h"),
    Node("i"),
    Node("j")));

postOrder(0, 1) (tree);
```

In particular, I'd like to avoid creating new nodes so that I can traverse arbitrary trees without having to know anything about their constructors. Is there a way to do this and still remain tail recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**stack-safe**

My first answer solves this problem by writing our own functional iterator protocol. Admittedly, I was eager to share this approach as it's something I've explored in the past. Writing your own data structures is really fun and it can yield creative solutions to your problem - and you'd be bored if I gave out the easy answers first, wouldn't you?

```
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

const postOrderFold = (f = (a, b) => a, acc = null, node = Empty) =>
{
  const loop = (acc, [ node = Empty, ...nodes ], cont) =>
    isEmpty (node)
      ? cont (acc)
      : ???
  return loop (acc, [ node ], identity)
}

const postOrderValues = (node = Empty) =>
  postOrderFold ((acc, node) => [ ...acc, Node.value (node) ], [], node)

console.log (postOrderValues (tree))
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

Full solution included below for other readers...

```js
const Node = (x, ...xs) =>
  [ x, xs ]

Node.value = ([ value, _ ]) =>
  value

Node.children = ([ _, children ]) =>
  children
  
const Empty =
  Symbol ()
  
const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

const identity = x =>
  x

// tail recursive
const postOrderFold = (f = (a, b) => a, acc = null, node = Empty) =>
{
  const loop = (acc, [ node = Empty, ...nodes ], cont) =>
    isEmpty (node)
      ? cont (acc)
      : loop (acc, Node.children (node), nextAcc =>
          loop (f (nextAcc, node), nodes, cont))
  return loop (acc, [ node ], identity)
}

const postOrderValues = (node = Empty) =>
  postOrderFold ((acc, node) => [ ...acc, Node.value (node) ], [], node)

const tree =
  Node("a",
    Node("b",
      Node("e"),
      Node("f",
        Node("k"))),
    Node("c"),
    Node("d",
      Node("g"),
      Node("h"),
      Node("i"),
      Node("j")))
    
console.log (postOrderValues (tree))
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

**mutual recursion**

Somehow it's your questions that allow me to canvas my most inspired works. Back in the headspace of tree traversals, I came up with this sort of pseudo-applicative sum type `Now` and `Later`.

`Later` does not have a proper tail call but I thought the solution was too neat not to share it

```
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

const postOrderFold = (f = (a, b) => a, acc = null, node = Empty) =>
{
  const Now = node =>
    (acc, nodes) =>
      loop (f (acc, node), nodes)

  const Later = node =>
    (acc, nodes) =>
      loop (acc, [ ...Node.children (node) .map (Later), Now (node), ...nodes ])

  const loop = (acc, [ reducer = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
    isEmpty (reducer)
      ? acc
      : reducer (acc, rest)

  // return loop (acc, [ ...Node.children (node) .map (Later), Now (node) ])
  // or more simply ...
  return Later (node) (acc, [])
}
```

Mutual recursion demonstration

```js
const Node = (x, ...xs) =>
  [ x, xs ]

Node.value = ([ value, _ ]) =>
  value

Node.children = ([ _, children ]) =>
  children
  
const Empty =
  Symbol ()
  
const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

const postOrderFold = (f = (a, b) => a, acc = null, node = Empty) =>
{
  const Now = node =>
    (acc, nodes) =>
      loop (f (acc, node), nodes)
    
  const Later = node =>
    (acc, nodes) =>
      loop (acc, [ ...Node.children (node) .map (Later), Now (node), ...nodes ])
    
  const loop = (acc, [ reducer = Empty, ...rest ]) =>
    isEmpty (reducer)
      ? acc
      : reducer (acc, rest)
  
  // return loop (acc, [ ...Node.children (node) .map (Later), Now (node) ])
  // or more simply ...
  return Later (node) (acc, [])
}

const postOrderValues = (node = Empty) =>
  postOrderFold ((acc, node) => [ ...acc, Node.value (node) ], [], node)

const tree =
  Node("a",
    Node("b",
      Node("e"),
      Node("f",
        Node("k"))),
    Node("c"),
    Node("d",
      Node("g"),
      Node("h"),
      Node("i"),
      Node("j")))
    
console.log (postOrderValues (tree))
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

Comment: Got the plague a couple days ago and cannot process any information right now. You're the best, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We start by writing `Node.value` and `Node.children` which get the two values from your Node

```
// -- Node -----------------------------------------------

const Node = (x, ...xs) =>
  [ x, xs ]

Node.value = ([ value, _ ]) =>
  value

Node.children = ([ _, children ]) =>
  children
```

Next, we create a generic `Iterator` type. This one imitates the native iterable behavior, only our iterators are persistent (immutable)

```
// -- Empty ----------------------------------------------

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

// -- Iterator -------------------------------------------

const Yield = (value = Empty, it = Iterator ()) =>
  isEmpty (value)
    ? { done: true }
    : { done: false, value, next: it.next }

const Iterator = (next = Yield) =>
  ({ next })

const Generator = function* (it = Iterator ())
{
  while (it = it.next ())
    if (it.done)
      break
    else
      yield it.value
}
```

Lastly, we can implement `PostorderIterator`

```
const PostorderIterator = (node = Empty, backtrack = Iterator (), visit = false) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    visit
      ? Yield (node, backtrack)
      : isEmpty (node)
        ? backtrack.next ()
        : Node.children (node)
            .reduceRight ( (it, node) => PostorderIterator (node, it)
                         , PostorderIterator (node, backtrack, true)
                         )
            .next ())
```

And we can see it working with your `tree` here

```
// -- Demo ---------------------------------------------

const tree =
  Node ("a",
    Node ("b",
      Node ("e"),
      Node ("f",
        Node ("k"))),
    Node ("c"),
    Node ("d",
      Node ("g"),
      Node ("h"),
      Node ("i"),
      Node ("j")));

const postOrderValues =
  Array.from (Generator (PostorderIterator (tree)), Node.value)

console.log (postOrderValues)
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

Program demonstration

```js
// -- Node ----------------------------------------------

const Node = (x, ...xs) =>
  [ x, xs ]
  
Node.value = ([ value, _ ]) =>
  value
  
Node.children = ([ _, children ]) =>
  children

// -- Empty ---------------------------------------------

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const isEmpty = x =>
  x === Empty

// -- Iterator ------------------------------------------

const Yield = (value = Empty, it = Iterator ()) =>
  isEmpty (value)
    ? { done: true }
    : { done: false, value, next: it.next }
    
const Iterator = (next = Yield) =>
  ({ next })
  
const Generator = function* (it = Iterator ())
{
  while (it = it.next ())
    if (it.done)
      break
    else
      yield it.value
}

const PostorderIterator = (node = Empty, backtrack = Iterator (), visit = false) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    visit
      ? Yield (node, backtrack)
      : isEmpty (node)
        ? backtrack.next ()
        : Node.children (node)
            .reduceRight ( (it, node) => PostorderIterator (node, it)
                         , PostorderIterator (node, backtrack, true)
                         )
            .next ())
            
// -- Demo --------------------------------------------              

const tree =
  Node ("a",
    Node ("b",
      Node ("e"),
      Node ("f",
        Node ("k"))),
    Node ("c"),
    Node ("d",
      Node ("g"),
      Node ("h"),
      Node ("i"),
      Node ("j")));

const postOrderValues =
  Array.from (Generator (PostorderIterator (tree)), Node.value)
  
console.log (postOrderValues)
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

The variadic `children` field makes the algorithm a little more complicated compare to a Node type that only has `left` and `right` fields

The simplified implementation of these iterators makes them a bit easier to compare. Writing support for variadic children in the other iterators is left as an exercise to the reader

```
// -- Node ---------------------------------------------

const Node = (value, left = Empty, right = Empty) =>
  ({ value, left, right })

// -- Iterators ----------------------------------------

const PreorderIterator = (node = Empty, backtrack = Iterator ()) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    isEmpty (node)
      ? backtrack.next ()
      : Yield (node,
          PreorderIterator (node.left,
            PreorderIterator (node.right, backtrack))))

const InorderIterator = (node = Empty, backtrack = Iterator (), visit = false) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    visit
      ? Yield (node, backtrack)
      : isEmpty (node)
        ? backtrack.next ()
        : InorderIterator (node.left,
            InorderIterator (node,
              InorderIterator (node.right, backtrack), true)) .next ())

const PostorderIterator = (node = Empty, backtrack = Iterator (), visit = false) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    visit
      ? Yield (node, backtrack)
      : isEmpty (node)
        ? backtrack.next ()
        : PostorderIterator (node.left,
            PostorderIterator (node.right,
              PostorderIterator (node, backtrack, true))) .next ())
```

And a very special `LevelorderIterator`, just because I think you can handle it

```
const LevelorderIterator = (node = Empty, queue = Queue ()) =>
  Iterator (() =>
    isEmpty (node)
      ? queue.isEmpty ()
        ? Yield ()
        : queue.pop ((x, q) =>
            LevelorderIterator (x, q) .next ())
      : Yield (node,
          LevelorderIterator (Empty,
            queue.push (node.left) .push (node.right))))

// -- Queue ---------------------------------------------

const Queue = (front = Empty, back = Empty) => ({
  isEmpty: () =>
    isEmpty (front),
  push: x =>
    front
      ? Queue (front, Pair (x, back))
      : Queue (Pair (x, front), back),
  pop: k =>
    front ? front.right ? k (front.left, Queue (front.right, back))
                        : k (front.left, Queue (List (back) .reverse () .pair, Empty))
          : k (undefined, undefined)
})

// -- List ----------------------------------------------

const List = (pair = Empty) => ({
  pair:
    pair,
  reverse: () =>
    List (List (pair) .foldl ((acc, x) => Pair (x, acc), Empty)),
  foldl: (f, acc) =>
    {  
      while (pair)
        (acc = f (acc, pair.left), pair = pair.right)
      return acc
    }
})

// -- Pair ----------------------------------------------
const Pair = (left, right) =>
  ({ left, right })
```

Over-engineered? Guilty. You can swap out the interfaces above for nothing but JavaScript primitives. Here we trade the lazy stream for an eager array of values

```
const postOrderValues = (node = Empty, backtrack = () => [], visit = false) =>
  () => visit
      ? [ node, ...backtrack () ]
      : isEmpty (node)
        ? backtrack ()
        : Node.children (node)
            .reduceRight ( (bt, node) => postOrderValues (node, bt)
                         , postOrderValues (node, backtrack, true)
                         )
            ()

postOrderValues (tree) () .map (Node.value)
// [ 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'd', 'a' ]
```

Comment: This is great engineering. However, I am not sure if the additional complexity of iterators/generators both syntactically and in terms of control flow is worth it (stack safety w/o TCO can be achieved with trampolines as you know). Comprehensibility and simplicity are properties that a developer should also take into account. It's about the right balance.